# manually pre-assign which process should be killed by oom

Tags: out-of-memory

I have a process that writes large files to /tmp which happens to be a tmpfs. When starting the process, I don't know if I have enough RAM. The process doesn't use excessive RAM itself. So I have to suspect that I will run out of RAM while the process is running because my tmpfs keeps occupying more and more storage. What's the recommended way to kill that process when I run out of RAM (that way, writing to tmp stops immediately and some RAM of the process gets free and i can clean up manually without other processes running on the machine dying or crashing)? e.g. tell OOM in advance "kill that process first".